# Apply rule to column with external condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table formed by three columns: The first one is a letter and the second and third are numbers.
I want to divide column B by column C when in column A there is a 'c'. Otherwise returns the value of B.

Example:

```
A = np.random.choice(['c', 'p'], size = 10)
B = np.random.rand(10)
C = np.random.rand(10)
D = np.array(list(zip(A, B, C)))

D= pd.DataFrame(D, columns = ['A', 'B','C'])
D
```

I tried to use `np.where(D['A']== 'p', D['B']/D['C'], D['B'])` but it returns me an error.

Comment: Solved. For some reason, the B and C columns are converted into a string.

Comment: You should provide a clearer desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialise the dataframe directly from a dictionary.

```
>>> A = np.random.choice(['c', 'p'], size = 10)
>>> B = np.random.rand(10)
>>> C = np.random.rand(10)
>>> D = pd.DataFrame({"A":A, "B":B, "C":C})
>>> D.apply(lambda row: row["C"]/row["B"] if row['A'] == "c"  else row['B'], axis=1)
       A         B         C
0  c  0.059202  0.582464
1  p  0.616223  0.918981
2  c  0.004744  0.612056
3  p  0.841413  0.501560
4  c  0.847137  0.028005
5  p  0.352703  0.043995
6  c  0.651796  0.778321
7  p  0.687776  0.870029
8  c  0.652986  0.682864
9  p  0.111138  0.587294
```

An np.array holds objects of the same data type. Hence as given in the 
[docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in
>   the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array.
>   For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following:

```
A = np.random.choice(['c', 'p'], size = 10)
B = np.random.rand(10)
C = np.random.rand(10)
D = np.array(list(zip(A, B, C)))

D= pd.DataFrame(D, columns = ['A', 'B','C'])
D['B'] = D['B'].apply(float)
D['C'] = D['C'].apply(float)
```

The B and C columns are converted into a string. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Float to string to float conversion isn't recommended. Why not define directly as floats as per @greole's solution?